How to test and choose Exam
I'm going abroad to Canada to work in the private sector and I need to improve my English so that I can get a job. As far as I know, for this I need to take special exams IELTS, TOEFL, but I'm completely confused about how to test your knowledge in a way that is objective.
On the Internet, I found various versions of tests, such as this one and another https://www.cambridgeenglish.org/test-your-englis and a large number of different ones on the websites of English language centers.
Could you please advise me, if you have had such an experience, how to test myself and what kind of exam I need? Thank you.

Questions about exams, tests, and other resources either belong on Language Learning SE or maybe ELL Meta, not here. This is for factual questions, not recommendations.

The question is unclear: "I'm going abroad to Canada to work in the private sector" suggests you have already obtained a job, in which case is the fluency in English required for the visa? Or does the question assume that you will land a job, if only your English is good enough?

The short answer is that you need the test that your employer/educator requires. By the way,  you can't just "go to Canada to work".  You will need a visa.  You won't get a visa if you don't have a sponsor. Any of the English tests are "objective" but some are designed for particular purposes, such as university. You should do your own research,  visit websites.  Moving to Canada is difficult you will need to make a very great effort to achieve this!

You'll probably need level B1+ or B2+. If this were university, it would be Advanced= C1 level, or 8.0 IELTS. To start  with, get an IELTS Test book, Academic or General, complete with answers, and do two or three tests of the  Reading, and the listening (a book cannot evaluate your speaking or writing skills, you need a teacher for that) and see what you get. If your speaking is very poor, you won't improve at home alone.

https://www.ilac.com/blog/how-to-determine-english-levels/#:~:text=B1%2FCLB%205%2D7,migrant%20workers%20coming%20to%20Canada.

Thanks everyone!
@WeatherVane I meant the second one. So I have a good perspective to get a job, but still don't understand how to prepare for that. I'm going to work an assistant cook in luxury restaurant.

Note that Canadian law favours giving jobs to its own citizens, if there is a suitable candidate, although if the best Canadian applicant is barely adequate, and the non-resident is very good, it might be possible to hire them. Are you a highly skilled "assistant cook"? It would make sense to get to know the job names of the various cooks in a restaurant.
